# Changing reference level for contrasts changes results in R 3.0.2/lme4 1.1-2 vs. R 2.15.0/lme4 .999999-0

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I hope this is an appropriate forum to post this question. I recently upgraded my R software from 2.15.0 to 3.0.2. I also upgraded the lme4 package from .999999-0 to 1.1-2. After doing so, the results from one of my linear mixed models analyses have changed a bit unexpectedly. In some respects, I was expecting some change, as the lme4 developers very clearly stated that they had made some significant changes to some fundamental components in the package. However, the changes that I am seeing (described below) make me think that something else is awry. I will start by explaining the experimental design, which is quite simple and then the issue at hand.

My experiment is a basic repeated measures design. I used 24 "Items" that each appeared in three different "Conditions" (SmallClause_Som, NoSmallClause, SmallClause_NoSom). Levels of Condition were rotated across three presentation lists such that each Subject (45 total, each assigned to a particular list) only saw one level of each item.

I used lmer() for the analysis. Condition was entered in as a Fixed effect and "Subject" and "Item" were entered as Random effects.

The problem:
Using the current version of R 3.0.2 and lme4 1.1-2 with NoSmallClause as the reference level (and no weighting on any of the contrasts), the ConditionSmallClause_Som/NoSmallClause contrast produces a t value of 1.680.

But, when I change reference level to SmallClause_Som (to observe the one remaining contrast) I get not only a change in the polarity of the effect (plus to minus, as expected), but the values change as well.

When I use R 2.15.0 and lme4 .999999-0 (on another computer), I do not experience this issue. I get slightly different values, but they do not change (apart from the polarity) when I change reference level.

My colleague also tried my analysis for me using R 3.0.2 and a version of lme4 (pre version 1.0) (I don't know exactly which version, but it was before the major changes) and he also does not experience the issue.

R 2.15.0 lme4 1.1-2 (older) output:

```
> #set ref level
> test$Condition <- relevel(test$Condition, ref="NoSmallClause")

> #Model 4: Random slopes by Subject and Item
> test.lmer4=lmer(Rating~Condition+(1+Condition|Subject)+(1+Condition|Item),test, REML=FALSE)
> summary(test.lmer4)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood 
Formula: Rating ~ Condition + (1 + Condition | Subject) + (1 + Condition |      Item) 
   Data: test 
 AIC  BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 3930 4010  -1949     3898    3902
Random effects:
 Groups   Name                       Variance   Std.Dev. Corr          
 Subject  (Intercept)                0.98998765 0.994981               
          ConditionSmallClause_Som   0.00203374 0.045097 -1.000        
          ConditionSmallClause_NoSom 0.00019873 0.014097  1.000 -1.000 
 Item     (Intercept)                0.96231875 0.980978               
          ConditionSmallClause_Som   0.89924400 0.948285 -0.020        
          ConditionSmallClause_NoSom 0.62128577 0.788217 -0.256  0.361 
 Residual                            1.68810777 1.299272               
Number of obs: 1080, groups: Subject, 45; Item, 24

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                  2.9583     0.2584  11.447
ConditionSmallClause_Som     0.3639     0.2165   1.680
ConditionSmallClause_NoSom   0.1472     0.1878   0.784

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CnSC_S
CndtnSmlC_S -0.116       
CndtnSmC_NS -0.260  0.392

> #set ref level
> test$Condition <- relevel(test$Condition, ref="SmallClause_Som")
> 
> #Model 4: Random slopes by Subject and Item
> test.lmer4=lmer(Rating~Condition+(1+Condition|Subject)+(1+Condition|Item),test, REML=FALSE)
> summary(test.lmer4)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood 
Formula: Rating ~ Condition + (1 + Condition | Subject) + (1 + Condition |      Item) 
   Data: test 
  AIC  BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 3930 4010  -1949     3898    3902
Random effects:
 Groups   Name                       Variance  Std.Dev. Corr          
 Subject  (Intercept)                0.9023239 0.949907               
          ConditionNoSmallClause     0.0020340 0.045099 1.000         
          ConditionSmallClause_NoSom 0.0035039 0.059194 1.000  1.000  
 Item     (Intercept)                1.8238288 1.350492               
          ConditionNoSmallClause     0.8992237 0.948274 -0.687        
          ConditionSmallClause_NoSom 0.9804329 0.990168 -0.604  0.670 
 Residual                            1.6881050 1.299271               
Number of obs: 1080, groups: Subject, 45; Item, 24

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                  3.3222     0.3174  10.468
ConditionNoSmallClause      -0.3639     0.2165  -1.680
ConditionSmallClause_NoSom  -0.2167     0.2243  -0.966

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CndNSC
CndtnNSmllC -0.588       
CndtnSmC_NS -0.521  0.638
```

R 3.0.2 and lme4 1.1-2 (newer) output:

```
> #set ref level
> test$Condition <- relevel(test$Condition, ref="NoSmallClause")

> #Model 4: Random slopes by Subject and Item
> summary(test.lmer4)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['lmerMod']
Formula: Rating ~ Condition + (1 + Condition | Subject) + (1 + Condition |      Item) 
   Data: test 

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance 
 3942.557  4022.312 -1955.278  3910.557 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name                       Variance Std.Dev. Corr       
 Subject  (Intercept)                0.9522   0.9758              
          ConditionSmallClause_NoSom 0.1767   0.4204    0.03      
          ConditionSmallClause_Som   0.1760   0.4196   -0.15  0.92
 Item     (Intercept)                1.2830   1.1327              
          ConditionSmallClause_NoSom 0.7782   0.8822   -0.41      
          ConditionSmallClause_Som   1.4901   1.2207    0.09  0.41
 Residual                            1.6466   1.2832              
Number of obs: 1080, groups: Subject, 45; Item, 24

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                  2.9583     0.2814  10.512
ConditionSmallClause_NoSom   0.1472     0.2133   0.690
ConditionSmallClause_Som     0.3639     0.2741   1.327

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CSC_NS
CndtnSmC_NS -0.357       
CndtnSmlC_S -0.007  0.451
> #anova (test.lmer3, test.lmer4)
> 
> #set ref level
> test$Condition <- relevel(test$Condition, ref="SmallClause_Som")
> 
> #Model 4: Random slopes by Subject and Item
> test.lmer4=lmer(Rating~Condition+(1+Condition|Subject)+(1+Condition|Item),test, REML=FALSE)
> summary(test.lmer4)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['lmerMod']
Formula: Rating ~ Condition + (1 + Condition | Subject) + (1 + Condition |      Item) 
   Data: test 

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance 
 3951.357  4031.113 -1959.679  3919.357 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name                       Variance Std.Dev. Corr       
 Subject  (Intercept)                0.88980  0.9433              
          ConditionNoSmallClause     0.04299  0.2073   0.83       
          ConditionSmallClause_NoSom 0.01562  0.1250   0.90  0.67 
 Item     (Intercept)                2.39736  1.5483              
          ConditionNoSmallClause     0.72053  0.8488   -0.04      
          ConditionSmallClause_NoSom 1.87804  1.3704   -0.16  0.53
 Residual                            1.65166  1.2852              
Number of obs: 1080, groups: Subject, 45; Item, 24

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                  3.3222     0.3525   9.425
ConditionNoSmallClause      -0.3639     0.2004  -1.816
ConditionSmallClause_NoSom  -0.2167     0.2963  -0.731

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CndNSC
CndtnNSmllC -0.045       
CndtnSmC_NS -0.160  0.514
```

My question:
What is going on here? Why is changing the reference level producing a shift from 1.327 to -1.816 in the t scores for the new version of lme4 whereas it produces the same (disregarding sign) value of 1.680/-1.680 in the old version's t scores? Only the older version seems to make sense to me.

1) Am I specifying my model incorrectly for the new version of lme4?

2) Am I missing some basic fundamental fact about how contrasts work? That is, is it possible to get different values just from changing the reference level? (the correlation values look a bit odd in the newer output).

3) Is this a bug in lme4?

4) Some other explanation...?

I have had some other odd issues as well with this same analysis using lme4 1.1-2. For example, if I don't clear the workspace and re-run an analysis, the values also will change between analyses (and also within the analysis as I change the reference level). This never happened to me on the earlier version (and it still does not happen when I run it on the earlier version now).

I hope someone can help with this. I found two other similar questions online (after much searching) but neither had any informative responses.

Thanks DT

Comment: You set ref level the same but the other two levels are in a different order across the first analyses here.

Comment: Thanks - but does that matter? It's still the same levels being compared against the same levels (apart from the missing contrast in the second version of Model 4 in the two runs), right? And it all comes out the same in the earlier implementation of lme4.

Comment: A missing contrast does matter. I don't know about the order, try it.

Comment: Hi John. What I meant by missing contrast is that when I change the reference level, the available contrasts should change. One will not be available. but this is to be expected. If I compare A and B to C, then the A:B comparison is missing. If I compare A and C to B, then the A:C comparison is missing. The order of the output is changing between R/Lme4 versions for some reason, but the data and code, including contrast specification are exactly the same.

Comment: Did you look at the order of the levels and verify they are the same? Are default contrasts set the same (options)?

Comment: This may be a bug in `lme4`, although it also looks like you may be overfitting the model.  Your 'old' fit has perfect correlations among the `Condition|Subject` terms, wherease the 'new' one doesn't; however, the 'old' fit has a considerably lower negative log-likelihood.  I suspect this is a rather unstable model fit, which would explain the differences between R versions (i.e., numerical instability) but I would like to look at the data if you're willing to send it -- in particular, I'd like to see if recently implemented convergence tests detect a problem.

Comment: In the short term, you could try `control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa")` and see if you get back to AIC ~ 3930 (rather than AIC ~ 3942).

Comment: Ben - you are right that I am overfitting the model by adding in the Subject slopes. I should not have these in (though I very generally feel that there is an expectation in my field to keep them in the model regardless - which might just be a misunderstanding on my part as to what "keeping it maximal" for example means). When I remove the Subject slopes and step back to only having Item specified for slopes, then I do get the same results regardless of reference level in both the "old" and "new" R installs. I can still send the data to your uni address if you for your convergence tests.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is an issue with the default Nelder-Mead optimizer, although I don't especially know why it should switch between R installations. I do get appropriate convergence warnings in the development version, and everything looks OK with the bobyqa optimizer (we are considering switching the default to bobyqa in an upcoming release).  Please try `control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa")` and see if that addresses the problem ...

Comment: I did try the optimizer command, but it seems like it increased the AIC instead of decreasing it. Perhaps I am not executing it at the right point though.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try (for the new lme4) to add

    `lmerControl("bobyqa")`

which uses a different optimizer than `"Nelder-Mead"` which had become the default,
and we (lme4 developers) have considered replacing the default optimizer and use
"bobyqa" as default.

In addition (and in any case):  Would you be willing to share your data and allow us to add them to the package "extra testing examples"?

Comment: Martin - I am getting the same results (on the "new" lme4 version) when I specify bobyqa or Nelder-Mead at the start of my lmer code. I am clearing old commands from the workspace before running (the results change if I do not do so). I emailed my data and code to Bolker's uni email address. You have my permission to use them in your package.

Comment: I should clarify that I am still looking at the change for the Model 4 (the over-fit model) results.

Comment: Hi. I still have not resolved this issue. The values still change with re-leveling, and I am now noticing that this occurs on both old (pre-1.0)  and new (post 1.0) versions of lme4. One thing I have noticed is that in the old versions of lme4, adding random slopes for Condition is a significant improvement to the fit, but in new versions it is not significant. Whenever I omit Random slopes, the problem with re-leveling goes away. it was suggested above that I am over-fitting my models. But I am not really sure how to verify that my models are not over-fit. Is anova not reliable?